# How to Show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_2\leq \|A\|_1\leq \sqrt{n}\|A\|_2$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation

I am trying to show that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_2\leq \|A\|_1\leq \sqrt{n}\|A\|_2.$$
I start with the definition
$$
\|A\|_2=\max_{v\neq 0}\frac{\|Av\|_2}{\|v\|_2}
.$$
I know that $\forall v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\|v\|_2\leq\|v\|_1$. But I do not know how to relate this property to the question at hand. For instance, is $\|Av\|_2\leq\|Av\|_1$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901233/proving-result-on-matrix-norms

Comment: @ArnaudD. I am still a bit confused. I don't know how $$\max_{v\neq 0}\frac{\|Av\|_2}{\|v\|_2}\leq \max_{v\neq 0}\frac{\sqrt{n}\|Av\|_1}{\|v\|_1}\implies\|A\|_2\leq\sqrt{n}\|A\|_1,$$ which establishes the first part of the inquality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_2\leq\|A\|_1$.