# Bounding the entries of a matrix by its norm

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Let $A$ be a $n$ by $n$ real matrix. Let $\|A\|$ denote the operator norm with respect to the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I want to prove there exist constants $c$ and $C$ depending only on $n$ such that
$$
c \| A \|\leq \max_{i,j} |A_{i,j}| \leq C \| A \|
$$

How can I prove this? Thank you!

ps if this question is too basic, I would also appreciate a reference

Comment: Please do not just ask. Show some work. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\|A \|=\max_\limits{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\|$, we have that:
$$\|A\| \geq \|Ae_j\| \ \forall \ j=1,\dots, n \ ,$$
where $e_j$ is the $j$th vector of the canonical basis (i.e. all zeros and a $1$ in position $j$).

But, letting $A^{(j)}$ be the $j$th column of $A$, we have:
$$\|Ae_j\| = \| A^{(j)} \| \geq  \max_i |A_{i j}| \ .$$

Since it holds for each $j$, it means that:
$$\| A\| \geq \max_{i,j=1,\dots, n} |A_{i j}| \ .$$

For the other side of the inequality, we have that:
$$\| A\| = \max_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\| = \max_{\|x\|=1}\left\|A\sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i \right\| \ ,$$
where we re-write $x$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Now, distributing the sum over the product, we have:
$$\max_{\|x\|=1}\left\|A\sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i \right\| 
= \max_{\|x\|=1}\left\|  \sum_{i=1}^n x_iAe_i \right\| \  
\leq  \max_{\|x\|=1}\left\|  \sum_{i=1}^n 1 \cdot A^{(i)} \right\|  
= \left\|  \sum_{i=1}^n A^{(i)} \right\| \ ,$$
where we used the fact that $\|x\|=1 \implies |x_i| \leq 1 \ \forall \ i$.

Now we can conclude because:
$$\left\| \sum_{i=1}^n A^{(i)} \right\| 
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \|A^{(i)} \| 
\leq n\max_i \|A^{(i)} \| 
\leq n \cdot n \cdot \max_{i,j = 1,\dots,n} |A_{i j}| 
= n^2 \max_{i,j =1,\dots,n} |A_{i j}|  \ .$$

Comment: This question seems not to meet the [standards for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.

Comment: my question needs to be better, but it was a nice answer. thank you!